# UITableView error

Tags: iphone, uitableview

ViewController.m

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface PSLEViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *highScoreTable;
}

@property(retain,nonatomic) UITableView *highScoreTable;
```

Error:

```
2010-12-04 02:20:15.541 PSLE[14369:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[PSLEViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b13080'
2010-12-04 02:20:15.542 PSLE[14369:207] Stack: (
```

Comment: Your post is hard to read the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing wrong with that code. There may be some other underlying issues, maybe in a `XIB`. Are you sure the `highScoreTable` is connected?

Comment: ya the table is connected. therefore i dun noe what is the error.

Comment: If you don't have any other views in that controller, I would suggest changing UIViewController to UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the **dataSource** and **delegate** of UITableView in **-(void)viewDidLoad**?
They should not be nil after loaded from nib.

Answer (score 0):

hai FYI are you allocate the tableView properly? check it out please

example `highScoreTable = [[UITableView alloc]init];`